# cordova-plugin-dialogs Beep stops working after 30 Times

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

i'm using Cordova 6.5.0 and the cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.1 with an Android MobileScanner.

Im playing a beep sound and showing the scan result everytime when the user scans a barcode with this function:

```
navigator.notification.beep(1);
console.log(scanresult);
```

The problem is, that the beep is silent after 30 Scans. The function is called but the beep is silent. The Scan Result is set everytime correctly.

After restarting the App, the Beep works for 30 Scans, but for the following scans, scan result is correct, beep is silent.

Maybe someone know this issue.

Thx for ur help.
Best Regards RonsonHD

Comment: do you have a latest plugin ?

Comment: the newest installed via cli and also an older version 1.2.1 tried, but same situation

Comment: what is the API vesion of your app ?

Comment: cordova android platform 6.1.2 (API 23 i think) or which api u mean?
on the device it self is android 4.4.2, should i downgrade the cordova platform version? or is it backward compatible

Comment: Android API or the Android app version on which you are installing apps?

Comment: Device Android 4.4.2 (API 19), Cordova Project Andorid Version 6.1.2 (API23)

Comment: Ive tried now with cordova android 4.1.1, same, tried with older plugin version same ;(

Comment: ok,let me drive through it again !!

Comment: Maybe someone got the same problem, ive resovled it with a workaround. I've added in my scanplugin the beep with android native code:
`final ToneGenerator toneGen1 = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
       toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP,100);
       Timer timer = new Timer();
       timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
        public void run() { 
         toneGen1.stopTone();
         toneGen1.release();
        }
       }, 100);`

Comment: you have scheduled external timer to play the tone,its not the proper solution,but till the time we can't find why its happening,its accepted